# Avoid patches while re-sizing any column of clistctrl in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

When I re-size any column of `clistctrl`(with report view) which is loaded with `UxTheme.dll`, it creates patches at the end of all the items(as shown in the image below 'Item 4').

[image]

Why does these patches occur and how to avoid those patches?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed some code that provides the context of your problem.

Comment: @rrirower i created the CListCtrl which is loaded library "UxTheme.dll", this patch occurs, otherwise this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a painting issue. What you're calling "patches" are artifacts that remain on-screen from the column divider line being moved.

You say that the problem is connected to the loading of the library UxTheme.dll. That implies you're setting the Explorer theme for your ListView control. That theme is designed to be used with double buffering. To accomplish that, you need to set the `LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER` extended style flag for the control.

```
myListCtrl.SendMessage(LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER, LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);
```